# Google Bigquery - Invalid query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have made the following query (standard SQL) in Google BigQuery (see below), but it results in an error. Does anyone know what's going wrong? In the query, I masked the project-id and dataset-id for confidential reasons.

Does anyone know how to work around the error and have a correct query? Thanks a lot in advance!

Required dimensions:

```
Date
hits.product.productSKU
custom dimension 47 (= product scope dimension)
custom dimension 48 (= product scope dimension)
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type
hits.eCommerceAction.step
```

Required metrics:

```
COUNT(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type)
COUNT(hits.product.productSKU)
```

The following error appears in the query below:

```
"Cannot access field productSKU on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<productSKU STRING, v2ProductName STRING, v2ProductCategory STRING, ...>> at [3:16]"
```

Query:

```
SELECT
date AS Date,
hits.product.productSKU AS SKU,
(
SELECT
cd.value
FROM
hits.customDimensions AS cd
WHERE
cd.index=47 ) AS CD47,
(
SELECT
cd.value
FROM
hits.customDimensions AS cd
WHERE
cd.index=48 ) AS CD48,
hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Type,
hits.eCommerceAction.step AS Step,
COUNT(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type) AS Nr,
COUNT(hits.product.productSKU) AS NrSKU
FROM
`[projectid].[datasetid].ga_sessions*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181103'
AND '20181103'
AND hits.page.hostname = 'www.bla.nl'
GROUP BY
Date,
Step,
Type,
SKU,
CD47,
CD48
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of entries in the `product` arrays? Maybe you want `SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product))` instead.

Comment: it seems that your `hits.product` field is an array of struct. Could you confirm? If so, you will have to unnest it.

Comment: @Teddy, confirmed. Unnesting works.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, thanks. What is the advantage of using SUM(ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... Cannot access field productSKU on a value with type ARRAY> ...

Below addresses above issue [only] and assumes that the rest of logic is correct and should return whatever OP expects to be returned

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE AS DATE,
  prod.productSKU AS SKU,
  ( SELECT cd.value
    FROM hits.customDimensions AS cd
    WHERE cd.index=47) AS CD47,
  ( SELECT cd.value
    FROM hits.customDimensions AS cd
    WHERE cd.index=48 ) AS CD48,
  hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Type,
  hits.eCommerceAction.step AS Step,
  COUNT(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type) AS Nr,
  COUNT(prod.productSKU) AS NrSKU
FROM `[projectid].[datasetid].ga_sessions*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits, UNNEST(hits.product) prod
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181103' AND '20181103'
AND hits.page.hostname = 'www.bla.nl'
GROUP BY DATE, Step, Type, SKU, CD47, CD48
```

As you can see here - I added `UNNEST(hits.product) prod` and replaced references to `hits.product.productSKU` with `prod.productSKU`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail, this works! There is only one more issue: the 2 product custom dimensions give value 'null' for all rows. Changing 'FROM hits.customDimensions AS cd' to 'FROM hits.product.customDimensions AS cd' does not work unfortunately. Do you also know a fix for this problem?

Comment: feedback on my previous comment: I already fixed it by changing 'hits.customDimensions' to 'prod.customDimensions'. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unnest the `product`. Here is an example using public ga data:

```
select date, productSKU, CD47, CD48, Type, Step, avg(array_length(nr)), avg(array_length(skus))  from (
  SELECT
    date AS Date,
    array((select p.productSKU as productSKU from unnest(hits.product) p)) skus,
    (SELECT cd.value FROM hits.customDimensions AS cd WHERE cd.index=47) AS CD47,
    (SELECT cd.value FROM hits.customDimensions AS cd WHERE cd.index=48) AS CD48,
    hits.eCommerceAction.action_type AS Type,
    hits.eCommerceAction.step AS Step,
    array((select hits.eCommerceAction.action_type)) AS Nr
  from 
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, unnest(hits) hits
), unnest(skus) productSKU
group by 
date, 
productSKU, 
CD47, 
CD48, 
Type, 
Step
```